# USB 3.0 header/device anomaly

Tags: usb, motherboard, front-panel

I have a strange issue with a new motherboard.

When I connect my old USB 3.0 front panel to the new motherboard's internal USB 3.1 header, I have one USB hard drive that does not function properly. In debugging using USBview (MS Windows Kit), I noticed that ALL ports show somewhat different than when connected to a PCIe card with USB 3.0 header.

When using the MB header, all of the ports show "Companion Port Number: 0" and no corresponding "Companion Hub Symbolic Name Link", and the one drive fails only when writing and all the other drives work. When using the PCIe header, there is a non-zero "Companion Port Number" and corresponding "Companion Hub Symbolic Name Link" information, and the drive works. When using the rear USB 3.1 ports on the MB, all is well also.

Can anyone explain the significance of the difference? i.e. the Companion Port Number?

Any help finding the root issue here? Drivers? Platform drivers? Combination?

Thanks in advance.

Note 1: the mb is ASRock w/ AMD B450, the front panel is Rosewill, the disk is WD, and the enclosure shows as an Initio device.

Note 2: acquired a 2nd front panel and no changes were observed when connected to MB header.

Comment: “When I connect my old USB 3.0 front panel to the new motherboard's internal USB 3.1 header, I have one USB hard drive that does not function properly.” - Why are you doing this?  Unless your internal USB 3.1 header is Gen 1 this does not make sense.  (USB 3.1 Gen 1 is USB 3.0)

Comment: I'm doing this because there is only one USB 3.x header on the motherboard. Yes, it is USB 3.1 gen 1. It should be backward compatible with the USB 3.0 front panel. All other devices work fine.

Comment: Additional observation: This behavior is limited to the USB 3.1 Gen 2 hub, which includes the (allegedly) Gen 1 header.